# How to output slf4j log messages from sbt?

Tags: scala, logging, sbt, slf4j

I'm currently writing an sbt plugin. The tasks that I define are using functionality from libraries that are otherwise unrelated to sbt and that I don't want to change. These libraries use slf4j for logging. I would like the logging output to show up in the sbt console as if I had used `streams.value.log`, so that I can e. g. turn debug logging on and off in the usual sbt ways like `set someTask / logLevel := Level.Debug`. Is there a way to do this?

It seems like sbt-slf4j is supposed to solve my problem:

https://index.scala-lang.org/eltimn/sbt-slf4j/sbt-slf4j/1.0.4?target=_2.12

But I wasn't able to get it to work. My `project/build.sbt` looks like this:

```scala
libraryDependencies += "com.eltimn" %% "sbt-slf4j" % "1.0.4"
resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("eltimn", "maven")
```

and `build.sbt` like so:

```scala
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.slf4j.impl.SbtStaticLoggerBinder

val foo = taskKey[Unit]("foobar")

foo := {
  SbtStaticLoggerBinder.sbtLogger = streams.value.log

  // symbolic implementation, the actual implementation lives in a library
  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("foobar")
  logger.warn("Hello!")
}
```

But running `foo` does not result in a warning being printed. A warning is printed if I change it to `LoggerFactory.getLogger(streams.value.log.name)`, but this is not an option because again, the code lives in a library.

Is there any good way to solve this?